# Send a message within 2 minutes after a user click on a callback query button telegram bot in php

Tags: php, database, telegram-bot, sendmessage

I want to send message to user after 2 minute he has clicked an callback query and execute database automatically after that 2 minute .

Comment: "**Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first.** Users here respond negatively if your question gives them the impression that you're asking them to do your work for you." --> [Quoted from here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Bro i didn't want sb to solve my problem instead of me .i just asked for a word that i could use to solve my problem with it.tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table called `jobs` and set a cron job to run every minute to check if there is any job to run. So you create a job for doing what you want and consider a column named `runs_at`.

| id | command | runs_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `{ "class_name": "DatabaseQueryJob", "parameters": { ... } }` | 2022-06-15 15:22:00 |

You have a class for running database queries and save what you need in parameters. Delete executed jobs from table and that's it.

I hope this idea solves your problem and let me know if I misunderstood you.

Comment: I used cron jobs bro but they are 1 minute period time .i want a realtime system to run extra code beside my main code every second:)

Comment: I used cron jobs bro but they are 1 minute period time .i want a realtime system to run extra code beside my main code every second or after exactly a time defined by myself after user's reaction :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [sleep](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function

```
switch($callbackdata){  ## Or whetever you named it
    case 'example':
        sleep(120);
        sendMessage($id, "Message");
        ## CODE TO BE EXECUTED
        break;
    case 'secondexample':
        .....
        break;
}
```